# Using Ufasoft miner with 50BTC

Tags: miner-configuration, cpu

So I decided to take a look at this bitcoin stuff. I would like to test Ufasoft for CPU mining. Don't really care about performance.

There is this nice guide: https://50btc.com/en/articles/view/68

And I follow the steps:

- Download http://ufasoft.com/open/bitcoin/
- Install it
- Run `"%ProgramFiles%\Ufasoft\Coin\coin-miner.exe"-u you@email.com -o http://pool.50btc.com:8332`

After running that, well, the command line stays there, with no feedback whatsoever. I can't type anything on it so I guess it is indeed doing something.

Anyway, out of curiosity I check out the activity monitor, and the CPU usage is almost always at 1% or 2%. Sometimes it may suddenly pick to 5%.

I was under the impression that CPU mining would cause some sort of greater spike, so I'm not sure if the miner is actually doing something.

It then ocurred to me to, of course, check out the 50BTC dashboard.

I have a worker, whose name is the same as my account name (which is the email address I used to startup the miner), so I guess this worker is the one that should be showing some sort of feedback. However, it says it is "offline", so it seems like, after all, the miner is indeed doing nothing.

Normally I'd just go on and try another miner, but I'd like to solve this anyway.

What have I done wrong?

I'm on Windows 7 with 4 cores. GPU mining has worked fine with software such as BitMinter in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Check your internet connection, make sure your mining device connected right, restart your devices.